# Setting DataContext for ContextMenu in ItemsControl.DataTemplate

Tags: wpf

I have custom control that is being used in data template for an ItemsControl.  I want to put a ContextMenu on each item and have it call the UserControl's View Model to process the command.  Using the XAML below, I can get click events on the custom control to call the SelectedItemCommand in the user control view model.  But, using similar syntax for the context menu fails.  By default I get the view mode per each custom control.  Any of the RelativeSource syntax value I use don't resolve to the user control's view model (RelativeSource Self).

What's the magic code?

```
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <controls:MyCustomItem Width="Auto"
                                                 Command="{Binding DataContext.SelectedItemCommand,
                                                                   RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,
                                                                                                  AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}}"
                                                 CommandParameter="{Binding}">
                    <controls:MyCustomItem.ContextMenu>
                        <ContextMenu>
                            <MenuItem Command="{Binding DataContext.ClearAlarmsCommand,
                                                        RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,
                                                                                       AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}}"
                                      Header="Clear All" />
                        </ContextMenu>
                    </controls:MyCustomItem.ContextMenu>
                </controls:MyCustomItem>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: You can't use `RelativeSource` binding for ContextMenu, because it uses a Popup which is outside of the visual tree.  Can you try an `ElementName` binding?  That might work, but I can never remember ...

Comment: Another option would be to use a Freezable as a Binding Proxy. Bind the Freezable to the ItemsControl's DataContext in the UserControl.Resources and then you can bind to the Freezable in the ContextMenu binding. I can post an example as an answer after lunch if no one gives a better solution by then.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**`ContextMenu doesn't lie in same Visual Tree`** as that of ItemsControl. Hence RelativeSource and ElementName won't work in Binding because they traverse Visual tree to found the source.

If you are using WPF 4.0 or higher you can use **`x:Reference`** markup extension to bind with ItemsControl dataContext.

Set `x:Name` on ItemsControl and bind using `x:Reference` like this:

```
<ItemsControl x:Name="itemsControl">
   ....
   <MenuItem Command="{Binding DataContext.ClearAlarmsCommand,
                               Source={x:Reference itemsControl}}"
             Header="Clear All" />
   ....
</ItemControl>
```

---

Also you can use **`Freezable BindingProxy`** approach if you are targeting version lower than WPF 4.0. Refer to my answer over [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21356695/632337) for the approach.

Comment: Thank you, master. It works! I've been looking for a solution for some time. Now I learned a new thing in WPF! Thanks.

Comment: man you saved my life! 2hours of unsuccessfully trying all the other approaches, I was about to give up, but then this beauty! Thanks!