# DataGridComboBoxColumn.ItemsSource. Binding vs EditingElementStyle

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

There are 2 XAML, why the second work, and the first is not?

cs:

```
public partial class myClass: Window
{
  public static DependencyProperty RoutersPortsViewProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("RoutersPortsView", typeof(DataView), typeof(myClass));

  public myClass()
  {
    DataTable MyTable = new DataTable();
    /*here fill MyTable*/
    SetValue(RoutersPortsViewProperty, new DataView(MyTable);
    InitializeComponent();
  }

  /*there other code for class*/
}
```

XAML not work:

```
<Window Name="myName" x:Class="myClass">
  <DataGrid>
    <DataGrid.Columns>
      <DataGridComboBoxColumn DisplayMemberPath="DisplayString" 
                              SelectedValuePath="id" 
                              SelectedValueBinding="{Binding Path=NWPatchPanelID, Mode=TwoWay, ValidatesOnExceptions=True, NotifyOnValidationError=True}" 
                              ItemsSource="{Binding Path=RoutersPortsView, ElementName=myName}"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
  </DataGrid>
</Window>
```

Error:

> *System.Windows.Data Error: 2 : Cannot find governing FrameworkElement or FrameworkContentElement for target element.
>   BindingExpression:Path=RoutersPortsView; DataItem=null; target element
>   is 'DataGridComboBoxColumn' (HashCode=11022751); target property is
>   'ItemsSource' (type 'IEnumerable')*

XAML work:

```
<Window Name="myName" x:Class="myClass">
  <DataGrid>
    <DataGrid.Columns>
      <DataGridComboBoxColumn DisplayMemberPath="DisplayString" 
                              SelectedValuePath="id" 
                              SelectedValueBinding="{Binding Path=NWPatchPanelID, Mode=TwoWay, ValidatesOnExceptions=True, NotifyOnValidationError=True}">
        <DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
          <Style TargetType="ComboBox">
            <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding Path=RoutersPortsView, ElementName=myName}"/>
          </Style>
        </DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
      </DataGridComboBoxColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
  </DataGrid>
</Window>
```

Comment: Did you create wrapper for RoutersPortsViewProperty?

Comment: @Spawn Of course! Then have a second option did not work too =)

Comment: Try Set the value after the  InitializeComponent();

Comment: @ДмитрийЧистик Set the DataContext of window as this.DataContext = this in the constructor after InitializeComponent, and itemsssource as ItemsSource="{Binding Path=RoutersPortsView}.

Comment: Also note that static fields should be initialized in static constructors only.

Comment: @AnjumSKhan This option will not work, because DataGrid have already installed another itemssource... for static variable everything is fine.

Comment: if i set in constructor `(dataGrid.Columns[0] as DataGridComboBoxColumn).ItemsSource = GetValue(RoutersPortsViewProperty ) as DataView;` it everything  work :( why not work for `ItemsSource->Binding` i not understand... :(((

Comment: solutions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25040512/bind-to-a-dependency-property-that-is-in-parents-datacontext . Are there any more solutions, not through a proxy object?

Answer (score 0):

Expose your DP in the form :

```
public DataView RoutersPortsView
        {
            get { return (DataView )GetValue(RoutersPortsViewProperty ); }
            set { SetValue(RoutersPortsViewProperty , value); }
        }
```